# Class not registered (Explorer.exe) on Windows Server 2008 via Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

I've got my local disks set to be accessible from remote connected Windows Server 2008.

When I open some location in the Windows Explorer, after some time or after re-connecting that location and all its contents become unavailable and when I try to navigate to a parent location I receive an error that says `Class not registered`.

I'm okay with that but how can I create a shortcut to that location without having to open folder by folder each time the location becomes unavailable?

I tried adding the location to favorites but it doesn't work unless I navigate to the desired folder all the way from root.

Comment: The title of your post suggests you want to resolve / troubleshoot a windows explorer error, while the question you ask pertains to creating shortcuts, which is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kitet Sorry for the misleading title. I'm pretty sure that this issue cannot be easily resolved so a workaround as a shortcut will be a sufficient solution.

Comment: Create a shortcut to any folder on the desktop of your server, (e.g. right-mouse-button-drag c: drive to the desktop and choose `create shortcut`), right-click again and choose `properties`. On the `shortcut` tab change contents of `target` field by manually typing fully qualified name of the folder you really need the shortcut to (e.g. `G:\folder1\subfolder2\and-so-on`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, mapping the location as a network drive resolved the issue.